# How is Discord Tokens, User IDs, Channel IDs etc created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, jwt

I'm wanting to replicate the ID system that Discord uses, for such as UserID/ChannelID/etc
and how a Discord Account Token (not 2fa) is generated.

I'm currently working a social platform system, and would love to use some of Discord's features for ideas in my project.

I don't have a clue as to where to start with either of these, is there any documention or examples of where I can see how it's done, I understand Discord is OpenSource but it's not fully OpenSource in the sense of the backend stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a small explanation of all the things you've asked.

### IDs

As described on the [API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#snowflakes) Discord is using [Twitter's snowflake](https://github.com/twitter-archive/snowflake/tree/snowflake-2010) format to generate ID. With that you can get the timestamp of generation and therefore you know when a channel, user or server has been created.

Feel free to read the documentation :D

### Tokens

Tokens don't match JSON Web Tokens and this is how they actually work:
[image: Discord Tokens Layout]

The timestamp value is no longer accurate, same for the "refresh" thing.

### Storing

Like most of the softwares they use a database to store their information. They used MongoDB and have now moved to **Cassandra**, see [this](https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-stores-billions-of-messages-7fa6ec7ee4c7) blog post. Now they moved to ** ScyllaDB** see [this](https://discord.com/blog/how-discord-stores-trillions-of-messages) blog post.

Comment: Thank you so much for the highly detailed explanation @Krypton.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they use a database
Apparently back in early 2015 they used mongodb
to store ids and tokens.

I am not completely sure what they use as of now.

Comment: They did, back in 2015 but I think they use Catalina or something silly like that.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question the user has asked.